# How can I do this animation using JS/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, svg, scroll, css-animations

I'm using CSS to animate a point along a path.
How can I perform this animation on scroll?
How can I calculate the position of a point depending on the path?

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 900 400">
  <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
    <path stroke="#29a0ec" stroke-width="2px" d="M22 1c417.705 78.667 631.039 274.847 640 588.542C657.222 953.18 436.555"></path>
  </g>
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #cff;
  height: 3000px;
}

.pulse1 {
  width: 55px;
  height: 55px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -17px;
  left: 25px;
}

.pulse1:before,
.pulse1:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  left: -5px;
  width: calc(100% + 10px);
  height: calc(100% + 10px);
  border: 1px solid rgba(41, 160, 236, 0.6);
  border-radius: 100%;
  -webkit-animation: pulse 3s linear infinite;
  animation: pulse 3s linear infinite;
}

.pulse1:after {
  top: -10px;
  left: -10px;
  width: calc(100% + 20px);
  height: calc(100% + 20px);
  -webkit-animation: pulse 3s linear infinite;
  animation: pulse 3s linear infinite;
}

.pulse2 {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.pulse2:before,
.pulse2:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  left: -5px;
  width: calc(100% + 10px);
  height: calc(100% + 10px);
  border: 1px solid rgba(41, 160, 236, 0.3);
  border-radius: 100%;
  -webkit-animation: pulse 3s linear infinite;
  animation: pulse 3s linear infinite;
}

.pulse2:after {
  top: -10px;
  left: -10px;
  width: calc(100% + 20px);
  height: calc(100% + 20px);
  -webkit-animation: pulse 3s linear infinite;
  animation: pulse 3s linear infinite;
}

.pulse3 {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}

.pulse3:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  left: -10px;
  width: calc(100% + 5px);
  height: calc(100% + 5px);
  border: 1px solid rgba(41, 160, 236, 0.6);
  border-radius: 100%;
  -webkit-animation: pulse 3s linear infinite;
  animation: pulse 3s linear infinite;
}

.pulse3:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  left: -5px;
  width: calc(100% - 5px);
  height: calc(100% - 5px);
  border: 1px solid rgba(41, 160, 236, 0.5);
  border-radius: 100%;
  -webkit-animation: pulse 3s linear infinite;
  animation: pulse 3s linear infinite;
}

.pulse4 {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(41, 160, 236, 1);
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  left: 3px;
}

.pulse4:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  left: -5px;
  width: calc(100% + 10px);
  height: calc(100% + 10px);
  background-color: rgba(41, 160, 236, 0.6);
  border-radius: 100%;
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1.4);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(1.8);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1.4);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(1.8);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 900 400">
      <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <path stroke="#29a0ec" stroke-width="2px" d="M22 1c417.705 78.667 631.039 274.847 640 588.542C657.222 953.18 436.555"></path>
        <circle cx="21.5" cy="1" r="5" fill="#29a0ec">
            <animateMotion id="animate" path="M22 1c417.705 78.667 631.039 274.847 640 588.542C657.222 953.18 436.555" begin="0s" dur="10s" repeatCount="indefinite" rotate="auto"></animateMotion>
        </circle>
      </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

[View on CodePen (with original SCSS)](https://codepen.io/yuriyupqode/pen/YmQPxj)

Comment: Please take a look at this pen [Another scroll animation a pen by Ivan Bogachev](https://codepen.io/sfi0zy/pen/wVJBGB)

Comment: Please include your code here rather than only on an external site. You can likely use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of point calculation for a simple **Quadratic Bezier** path:

```js
const a = {x: 20, y: 20};
const b = {x: 400, y: 20};
const c = {x: 480, y: 280};

const getCoordinate = (t,coord) => a[coord] * t * t + 2 * b[coord] * t * (1-t) + c[coord] * (1-t) * (1-t);

const qbPos = t => {
 
 const x = getCoordinate(t, 'x');
 const y = getCoordinate(t, 'y');
 return {x, y};
};

const point = document.getElementById("point");

const movePoint = t => {
 const pos = qbPos(t);
 point.setAttribute('cx', pos.x);
  point.setAttribute('cy', pos.y);
  
 t = t <= 0 ? 1 : t - 0.001;
 setTimeout(() => movePoint(t), 1);
};

movePoint(1);
```

```html
<svg width="500" height="300">
 <path d="M 20,20 Q 400,20 480,280" stroke-width="3" stroke="blue" fill="none"/>
 <circle id="point" cx="20" cy="20" r="10" fill="blue"/>
</svg>
```